# How to execute maven project from command line

Tags: maven, command-line

Below is the message I received every time when I ran MVN TEST on the project folder from command line.

```
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ----------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

My Testscripts location is below. I went to the below folder and ran mvn test from the command line.

```
/Copy of naukri/src/testScripts/NewTest.java
```

Below is the POM file of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>naukri</groupId>
    <artifactId>NewTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NaukriUpdate</name>
    <description>----------------</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>../src/testScripts/</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <testSourceDirectory>../src/testScripts/</testSourceDirectory> 
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>testScripts.NewTest</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>firefox</propertyName>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>     
            <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>                                                             
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about your problem. Have you tests ? If yes, give us more information about them (name, location in the source folder)...

Comment: Hello David. I have updated the question with more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First follow the conventions which means having source code in `src/main/java` the unit tests in `src/test/java` furthermore remove the configurations for sourceDirectory and testDirectory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your test in

> src/test/java

Please look at see documentation https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html